# how to cast each row of type varchar to array?

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, casting

So I have this problem. I have a table called Orders, where i have a column product_id, but it's of the type varchar, because there can be many of them e.g. '12,3,4,345'. They are all sepearted with ','
But my question is how can I cast in query each row of varchar to array?
I tried it with the string_to_array function, but it only casts one row. I need to cast all of the rows in the given table.

My code

```
SELECT o.product_id, string_to_array(
(select product_id
from orders), ',' ) as array
from orders o ;
```

I am working in IntellIJ, using JDBC driver on postresql database.

Comment: That's a horrible data model. Do you have any chance to fix it before you proceed?

Comment: No need for a SELECT: `string_to_array(product_id, ',' )` but again: fix your broken design first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice if you attach sample data and expected output. So far, I understood your problem, that you want to "put" the contents of each line into an array.

```
SELECT product_id,
(string_to_array(product_id, ',')::int[]) as array
from orders;
```

Check out [my dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=777c0d990755d30518d1cad661185e20) and let me know if the result is different from what you want.